TextVariable not working in replit tkinter python
I'm trying to make a simple entry widget but it's not working. For some reason even when I change the text the variable doesn't change. I don't know if it's my computer, replit or my code.
Here's the important part of the code:
nb_pourboire = tk.StringVar()
nb_pourboire.set("1")
txtPourboire = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=3, textvariable=nb_pourboire)

txtPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
txtPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.25)
   
lblPourboire["text"] = "Pourboire"
lblPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
lblPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.25)

if int(nb_employes.get()) <= 7:
     for i in range(int(nb_employes.get())):
         print(nb_employes.get())

When I run this and change the input box it still prints the default of 1.
Edit : I'm sorry for the lack of clarity earlier, here's the FULL code, I run the tk.StringVar() through a button function.
import tkinter as tk

# Initialisation des variables
taux_horaire_Secretaire = 16.55
taux_horaire_Comptable = 20
taux_horaire_Superviseur = 30
taux_horaire_Concierge = 10
taux_horaire_Marketeur = 20
commencer = False
Donnees = []

# Programme principal
# Met en place la fenêtre tkinter
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.geometry("600x800")  # Définit la résolution par défaut de la fenêtre
fenetre.configure(bg="gray15")  # Définit la couleur de la fenêtre en gris foncé
fenetre.title("Programme de Comptabilité")  # Définit le titre de la fenêtre

# Création des cadres
cadrePrincipal = tk.Frame(fenetre)
cadrePrincipal.config(bg="gray20", relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=3)
cadrePrincipal.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=300, ipady=50)

cadreSecondaire = tk.Frame(fenetre)
cadreSecondaire.config(bg="gray15", relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
cadreSecondaire.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=150, ipady=300)

cadreSommaire = tk.Frame(fenetre)
cadreSommaire.config(bg="gray95", relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
cadreSommaire.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=150, ipady=300)

# Labels principaux
lblTextePrincipal = tk.Label(cadrePrincipal)
lblTextePrincipal["text"] = "Nombre d'employés"
lblTextePrincipal.configure(font=("Arial", 12), bg="gray20", fg="white")
lblTextePrincipal.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.3)

lblMessage = tk.Label(cadrePrincipal)
lblMessage["text"] = "Erreur"
lblMessage.configure(font=("Arial", 8), bg="gray20", fg="white")
lblMessage.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.87)

# Fonction pour verifier des choses
def verifier_Int(nombre):
   try:
        int(nombre)
        return True
   except ValueError:
        print("Vous avez fais une erreur dans votre entrée de donnée. Un nombre n'est pas correct!") 
        lblMessage["text"] = "Vous avez fais une erreur dans votre entrée de donnée. Un nombre n'est pas correct!"
        return False

# Champ de saisie pour le nombre d'employés
nb_employes = tk.StringVar(fenetre, value="2")
txtNombreEmployee = tk.Entry(cadrePrincipal, textvariable=nb_employes)
txtNombreEmployee["text"] = "Nombre d'employés"
txtNombreEmployee.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
txtNombreEmployee.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.4, rely=.61)

# Fonction pour créer les employés
def cree_employes(i):
   # Variables pour les options des employés
   typeEmploi = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   lblTypeEmploi = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblNombreHeures = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblPourboire = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblNomEmploye = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   options = ["Secretaire", "Comptable", "Superviseur", "Concierge", "Marketeur"]
   optTypeEmploi = tk.OptionMenu(cadreSecondaire, typeEmploi, *options)
   nb_heures = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtNombreHeures = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=3, textvariable=nb_heures)
   nb_pourboire = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtPourboire = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=3, textvariable=nb_pourboire)
   nom_employe = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtNomEmploye = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=11, textvariable=nom_employe)
   
   # Label pour le cadre des employés
   lblTitreSecondaire = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblTitreSecondaire["text"] = "Employé " + str(i+1)
   lblTitreSecondaire.configure(font=("Arial", 12), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblTitreSecondaire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.05+2.8*(i/10))
   
   # Configuration et placement des éléments d'entrée pour chaque employé
   txtNomEmploye.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtNomEmploye.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.1+2.8*(i/10))

   lblNomEmploye["text"] = "Nom d'employé"
   lblNomEmploye.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblNomEmploye.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.1+2.8*(i/10))

   typeEmploi.set("Secretaire")
   optTypeEmploi.configure(fg="white", bg="gray20")
   optTypeEmploi.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.15+2.8*(i/10))

   lblTypeEmploi["text"] = "Type d'emploi"
   lblTypeEmploi.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblTypeEmploi.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.15+2.8*(i/10))

   txtNombreHeures.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtNombreHeures.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.20+2.8*(i/10))

   lblNombreHeures["text"] = "Nombres d'heures"
   lblNombreHeures.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblNombreHeures.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.20+2.8*(i/10))

   txtPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.25+2.8*(i/10))

   lblPourboire["text"] = "Pourboire"
   lblPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.25+2.8*(i/10))

   Liste = [nom_employe.get(), typeEmploi.get(), nb_heures.get(), nb_pourboire.get()]
   return Liste

# Fonction pour passer au prochain employé
def prochain_employe():
   lblTypeEmploi.place_forget()
   lblNombreHeures.place_forget()
   lblNomEmploye.place_forget()
   lblPourboire.place_forget()
   optTypeEmploi.place_forget()
   txtNombreHeures.place_forget()
   txtNomEmploye.place_forget()
   txtPourboire.place_forget()
   Liste = cree_employes(0)
   return Liste

# Fonction pour créer le sommaire
def cree_Sommaire():
   txt = ""
   for i in range(int(len(Donnees)/4)):
      txt = "Singe" + str(i)
      print(Donnees)

# Fonction pour démarrer le processus
def commencer_clique():
   global commencer
   global Donnees

   if verifier_Int(nb_employes.get()) and not commencer:
      commencer = True
      print(nb_employes.get())

      if int(nb_employes.get()) <= 7:
         for i in range(int(nb_employes.get())):
            Liste = cree_employes(i)
            for item in Liste:
               Donnees.append(item)

         # Création d'un widget bouton pour passer au Sommaire
         btnSommaire = tk.Button(cadreSecondaire, command=cree_Sommaire)
         btnSommaire.config(text="Sommaire", fg="white", bg="gray20", font=("Arial", 10))
         btnSommaire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.78)
      else:
         # Création d'un widget bouton pour passer au prochain employé
         btnProchain = tk.Button(cadreSecondaire, command=prochain_employe)
         btnProchain.config(text="Prochain Employé", fg="white", bg="gray20", font=("Arial", 10))
         btnProchain.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.78)

   elif commencer:
      print("Erreur, vous avez déjà commencé. Veuillez finir votre session d'abord.")
   else:
      print("Erreur, veuillez entrer un nombre entier.")

# Création d'un widget bouton pour commencer
btnCommencer = tk.Button(cadrePrincipal, command=commencer_clique)
btnCommencer.config(text="Commencer", fg="white", bg="gray20", font=("Arial", 10))
btnCommencer.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.66, rely=.6)

# Rend la résolution de la fenêtre inchangeable
fenetre.resizable(False, False)

# Lance la fenêtre
fenetre.mainloop()

PS: Don't worry about the rest of the errors hopefully i'll fix them I just wanna focus on this one specifically since I haven't been able to fix it since I started this project.
So I've just tried this to test if the variable is updating or not in a new script and it works just fine there. So clearly it's a mistake in the code, i just don't know what it could be.

If you're wondering why it says for i in range nb_emplyes then just printing it multiple times, I removed the part of the code that was required there since it's not important to the question. It might be the cause of the issue but i'm 99% sure it's not

You're calling nb_employees.get() about a millisecond after creating the input widget, well before the user has seen it and had a chance to type into it.

@BryanOakley Sorry for the lack of clarity i just updated my question

When you define Liste inside cree_employes, it’s still just a millisecond after creating the entry widgets.

txtNombreEmployee["text"] = "Nombre d'employés" is an error that destroys nb_employes StringVar.

most GUIs don't work like input() in console. Widgets don't wait for user data. Widgets only inform what mainloop has to display in window. And widget may have assigned/binded function which mainloop may execute when user put data in widget. Example is command= in Button - and this is common method: add button which user presses after putting data in widget, and this button runs function which gets data from widgets and it uses these values directly in this function (not outside).

for Entry you may bind even Return to execute function when user press button ENTER/RETURN and this function may get value (because user's data will be already in Entry) and use it directly in this function

other information - Button runs function from command= but you don't know when it will be - so mainloop can't get result from this function and using return List is useless in prochain_employe(). If you want this list to do something then do it directly in prochain_employe()

it would be simpler if you would always use English words in names of variables and functons. And there is suggestion to always use lower_case_names for variables and functions - e.g.cadre_principal , lbl_texte_principal - and CamelCaseNames only for classes - e.g. every widget is a class - Button, Entry. It helps to recognize class in code. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
